# html div floating and sizing

Tags: css, html, size

I want to make a web page that uses 100% of screen space. I have two divs:

1st - menu with fixed width (~250px)
2nd - whats left

The misleading part for me is that the menu div is not in the 2nd div. They both are in a wrapper div (100% width). The problem is that if I write 100% width for the 2nd div, it goes below the menu. If I write less %, I cannot be sure how it will be displayed in smaller resolutions.

Is there is some negative sizing or something? ATM. 1st div floats left and 2nd div float right.

**UDPATE:** here is some code:

```
div.main {
  width: 100%;
}
div.1st {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}
div.2nd {
  width: 100%; #here should be the space that is left in the main div#
  float: right;
}

<div class="main">
    <div class="1st">menu</div>
    <div class="2nd">content</div>
</div>
```

Problem: content could be as wide as it needs to so if string or objects in it is big enough 2nd div goes below 1st. Menu width is fixed.

**UPDATE #2:** if i leave content width empty then it will also goes below menu since content is wide enough

Comment: Can you add more meat to your question ?

Comment: Rachel has it right: Add your CSS and HTML, then we will be better equipped to help you :)

Comment: You don't need to put a width on the second div. Is this what you were looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/aXKze/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this Post, there you have the correct solution:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can determine the width of `absolute`ly positioned elements by setting `left` and `right`. This makes the browser solve the equation in the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) for `width`. See this [**demo**](http://phihag.de/2011/so/100percent.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/78x8y/

markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">Width=> 250px, float left</div>

    <!-- following div takes automatically the remaining width, no need to declare further css rules -->
    <div id="remaining">Width => the remaining space</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden; /* instead of clearfix div */
}
#left{
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    background:red;
}
#remaining{
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#DEDEDE;
}
```